# Database design - Foreign Key to unique attribute

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I would like to build user login database schema. 
 Following up with the convention, related data has to be gathered in separate tables and for each table only one primary key has to be defined. Accordingly, I've braked data in **login** and **user** tables.
Since, I want to use email as an username for login, I defined it as Foreign-Key in **login** table referencing to ***email*** attribute in user table. Also, in login table i have defined ***login_id*** as Primary Key, which is a Foreign-Key referencing to ***user_id*** attribute in users table.

[image]

Please advice, am I doing the design correctly and what is the best practice and approach?

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Alsos
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Alsos
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Alsos` ;
USE `Alsos` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Alsos`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Alsos`.`user` (
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `DoB` DATE NULL,
  `contact_number` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `social_link` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_email_UNIQUE` (`user_email` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB



-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Alsos`.`login`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Alsos`.`login` (
  `login_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `passwordHash` CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `passwordSalt` CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` DATETIME NULL,
  `last_seen` DATETIME NULL,
  `active` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  UNIQUE INDEX `accounts_id_UNIQUE` (`login_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) VISIBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`login_id`)
    REFERENCES `Alsos`.`user` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_username`
    FOREIGN KEY (`username`)
    REFERENCES `Alsos`.`user` (`user_email`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: If you have two foreign keys to the same row, you're violating database normalization and storing redundant data. You should just have one FK, the other is automatically implied.

Comment: And if the two tables have a 1-to-1 correspondence, there's no need to separate them, they should just be one table.